# Android - How to find Free fall duration when a free fall ends

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, hardware-acceleration

Please help me to find time duration when free fall ends in android. I have seen some code which is helping to find free fall, from that how we can find the duration of free fall. Thanks!

//Edit

I have used below code to find the free fall, just verified one device, in that I could able to find the free fall with below code.

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        double xForce = event.values[0];
        double yForce = event.values[1];
        double zForce = event.values[2];

        double accelerationReader = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xForce, 2)
                + Math.pow(yForce, 2)
                + Math.pow(zForce, 2));

        DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        double accRound = Double.parseDouble(precision.format(accelerationReader));

        if (accRound > 0.3d && accRound < 0.5d) {
            //finding free fall duration
            //LogEvent.builder().duration(duration).save(context);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: post relevant code

Comment: yeah, can you post the code you currently have on how to find the free fall? then we can work with it to turn it into what u need..

Comment: Ok i will add the code changes

Comment: @SimonMayrshofer I added the code changes which I used to find the free fall

Comment: @RishabhDhawan added

Comment: @SimonMayrshofer, Any updates on this query ?

Comment: hoan-nguyen Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Navaspk so what is it that you need help with? do you need to get a starter idea on how to measure the overall time of the freefall? is this for skydivers? Depending on your use case, it seems to me like you could run an `onTick()` and check whether you are still in free fall, e.g. every second, and then simply get the start and end time using `System.getCurrentTimeInMillis()`, and if you substract them you will have the over all free fall time. If you need help with this, I can give you some code? however it would be useful to know what the use scenario is / exactly what you need it for.

Comment: @SimonMayrshofer With above my code I have seen that, it could able to detect free fall some particular devices, but not able to detect free fall for some other set of devices. Basically I want to detect free fall and it's duration. Duration means when device falling from hand need to measure the overall time to free fall. Can you please help ?